# Em radiation incident on an atom

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, antennas

What happens when the EM wave is incident on a atom? Do the de-localized electrons in the atoms or the valence band electons move in the direction of the electric field? Also when the electrons move, does the magnetic field in the EM wave also exert a force on the moving electrons?

[image]

Comment: This question should be closed down as it has an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** this is a copy of my answer to OP's question on electronics.stackexchange.com. This might use notation that is not very typical in a physicist's context. It looks like the equations I've learned in my EE studies.

---

Remember the Schrödinger equation from which you know what a "delocalized electron" is?

$$ j\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(x,t) = \left [ - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + V(x,t)\right ] \Psi(x,t) $$

Exactly in that you insert your time-dependent (vector) potential $V(x,t)$. You'll see that the derivative of the \$\Psi\$ now has a harmonic component.

> Do the de-localized electrons in the atoms … move

Um, we *really* need to be careful when we say that something without a location moves... but, yes, the probability mass $\lvert\Psi(x,t)\rvert$ is time-dependent under a changing potential at a fixed point $x$. So, the electrons' loci "move" (with spoken-out quotation marks).

> Also when the electrons move, does the magnetic field in the EM wave also exert a force on the moving electrons?

Err. Now I'm not sure how we can interpret "moving": The electron's probability of occurrence "move"; the electrons themselves "stochastically interact"; this is quantum regime, you can't first call something "delocalized" and in the next sentence act as if it was a classical (i.e., non-quantum) particle.

To me, this sounds like you're trying to apply Maxwell's equations to quantum things. Don't. Schrödinger's equation is what you'll need deal with.